# Несколько методов на одну URL

Tags: java, api, spring-mvc

Нужно написать API, и у клиента есть примеры запросов, которые должны быть.

> **https://host.co.uk/localworld.aspx?req=nsr&em=some@email.com&sn=Name+Lname&uid=AE5C54C1-DA8B-4B81-A184-7FB7ED014FBB&pc=SG51PB&tc=LLM&st=ACTIVE&sd=20160722&ed=20161020&vr=78**
>
> **https://host.co.uk/localworld.aspx?req=evr&em=some@email.com**

и так дальше для остальных методов. Отличаются они только тем, что в `req` заходят разные параметры по дефолту. 
Но когда я пытаюсь написать контроллер, то мне выдает амбишиос ошибку, потому, что на ссылку `/localworld.apsx` уже имеется метод `POST`, а они все должны быть методами `POST`. 
Пример кода:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/localworld.aspx")
public class HHSController {

    @Autowired
    private HHSApiService apiService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
                    headers = "Accept=application/json",
                    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public EmailAddressDto emailValidation(@RequestBody @Valid EmailValidationDto dto) {
        return apiService.isValid(dto);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
                    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                    headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public HHSSubscriptionResponse subscribe(@RequestHeader(value = "x-ppauth-access") String accessKey,
                                             @RequestBody @Valid HHSSubscribe subscribe) {
        verifyForEmptyAccessKey(accessKey);

    return null;
}
```

}

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Autowired лучше вешать на конструктор. Вот так http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно использовать вот такой вариант

```
@RequestMapping("/localworld.aspx", params = "req=evr")
```

Comment: это нужно цеплять на каждый метод с его `req`, правильно?

Comment: @DimaKhodan да.

Comment: Такой еще вопрос. Как смысл писать `/localworld.aspx` если можно сделать это и без суфикса?

Comment: @DimaKhodan да. я это просто для примера сделал.

Comment: я вообщем имею ввиду. даже в плане клиента. это `.aspx`. же ничего не изменяет. 

да, так работает.

Comment: а клиента RESTу не научить?

Comment: не понял вопрос

Comment: если бы клиент использовал REST для общения с сервером, то было бы проще писать сервер. сейчас клиент использует не REST!